# EWS streaming notifications are not received after some time

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, office365api

I have a strange problem with the streaming events in EWS.

I have subscribed to a group of mailboxes using the needed cookies as mentioned here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn458789(v=exchg.150).aspx

After receiving notifications for some time, suddenly they stop to arrive ( usually after 40 minutes - 1 hour)
I tried to debug it with the EWS trace and noticed that "heartbeat" messages
that the exchange server sends periodically are no longer received, and example to this message:

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap11:Header xmlns:soap11="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <ServerVersionInfo xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" MajorVersion="15" MinorVersion="1" MajorBuildNumber="1178" MinorBuildNumber="21" Version="V2017_04_14" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" />
</soap11:Header>
<soap11:Body xmlns:soap11="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <m:GetStreamingEventsResponse xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
    <m:ResponseMessages>
      <m:GetStreamingEventsResponseMessage ResponseClass="Success">
        <m:ResponseCode>NoError</m:ResponseCode>
        <m:ConnectionStatus>OK</m:ConnectionStatus>
      </m:GetStreamingEventsResponseMessage>
    </m:ResponseMessages>
  </m:GetStreamingEventsResponse>
</soap11:Body>
```

I have set the OnDisconnect event to re-open the connection on timeout and saw that it works - so i guess its not a timeout problem.

Have anybody have a clue why the messages stop to arrive ?

Is the subscription is lost? should i re-subscribe ? 
(I didn't find any reference to this issue)

this is my code:

```
`static void ListenerFunciton()
{
// Set the exchange service
ExchangeService service = null;
service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013_SP1);
service.Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(ServiceAccount, ServicePassowrd);
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
 delegate (Object obj, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors errors)
 {
     return true;
 };

 string anchorMailbox = "blabla@domain.onmicrosoft.com"
 StreamingSubscription subsribption = null;

 //Set the coockies
 service.HttpHeaders.Add("X-AnchorMailbox", anchorMailbox);
 service.HttpHeaders.Add("X-PreferServerAffinity", "true");

 // Set the impersonation
 service.ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, anchorMailbox);

 subsribption = service.SubscribeToStreamingNotifications(new FolderId[] { WellKnownFolderName.Inbox }, EventType.NewMail);

 int index = service.HttpResponseHeaders["Set-Cookie"].IndexOf("X-BackEndOverrideCookie");
 string coockie = service.HttpResponseHeaders["Set-Cookie"].Substring(index).Split(';')[0];
 service.HttpHeaders.Add("Cookie", coockie);

 StreamingSubscriptionConnection connection = new StreamingSubscriptionConnection(service, 29);
 connection.AddSubscription(subsribption);
 connection.OnNotificationEvent += OnNotificationEvent;
 connection.OnDisconnect += OnDisconnect;
 connection.Open();
 while(true)
 {

 }

}

static private void OnDisconnect(object sender, SubscriptionErrorEventArgs args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\n\n\n\nFrom now this is the reconnection\n\n\n\n");
    //cast the sender object
    StreamingSubscriptionConnection connection = (StreamingSubscriptionConnection)sender;
    //reconnect
    connection.Open();

}

static private  void OnNotificationEvent(object sender, NotificationEventArgs args)
{
    file.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " || Got notification");
    file.Flush();
    foreach (NotificationEvent notification in args.Events)
    {
        file.WriteLine("From Subscription: "+args.Subscription.Id+" Event: "+notification.EventType.ToString("D"));
        file.Flush();
    }
    file.WriteLine("\n\n");
}`
```

Comment: Did you find any solution to your problem ?

Comment: After i have investigated this issue - it seems like microsoft is loosing the subscription from time to time (At least thats what happen with the Push method)

So my solution was to set an interceptor to the hearbeat messages, and then if in a certain interval of time there is not message - so re-subscribe

Comment: Same issue is observed with non-streaming version of the notifications. The heartbeat just stops after a while or if another event is fired. Really clumsy. sborpo's solution seems only way forward

Answer (score 2):

StreamingSubscriptionConnection has life time is 1-30, so after life time min Stream open connect, raise events and close connection.